# Properly query additional posts for wordpress category

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

My case is: I have a category and some seperately defined list of posts to always show on top of the category page. The actual or default posts are shown later in page 2, or via ajax.
By simply create a new WP_Query, this problem is solved, but wordpress actually executed a whole unnecessary process in the main query before that happened, which should only happen if the user request for page 2 or via ajax.
I used the hook 'pre_get_posts' to change the main query itself, but could only show these posts by category, not by defining list of posts.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is probably quite messy ... could you post the code you wrote and describe where you've added it?

Quick question: Have you tried creating a shortcode which returns the desired posts? You could then use the shortcode either inside of your backend using [your-shortcode] or your code using do_shortcode( 'your-shortcode' )?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a mis-test, here is my code and it worked:

```
function rewrite_main_query ($query ){
 if( $query->is_main_query() &&   $query->is_category){
     global $wp_query; 
     $postid=37; //the post id wanted
     $query->set('p',$postid);
 }  
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'rewrite_main_query');
```

Previously i used 'post__in' instead and did not work, i thought they functioned the same for 'post__in' and 'p' and did not tested it. It work now with 'p'.